# How to handle labels in x-axis in ellipsis format in Apexchart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

I want to show all the labels on x-axis in ellipsis format and onhovering the labels tooltip should show the actual context.

To achieve this, I tried two approaches:

The build-in property trim. By using this property I achieved the ellipsis property on labels but some of the labels skips from the UI because of their large length.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIrhN.png)

I use the formatter in labels but it also affects the tooltip on x-axis labels
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNodz.png)

I need to show all the labels in continuity and the tooltip should show actual context of the labels. Can anyone please help me to achieve this.

I need to show all the labels in continuity and the tooltip should show actual context of the labels. Can anyone please help me to achieve this.